# How to get specific map values from inside Freemarker template

Tags: java, freemarker

I need to pass a `Map<String,String>` into a Freemarker template, and then, inside the template, cherry pick which values I pluck from the injected map. So something like:

```
// This map will have a 'fizz' key with a String value of 'buzz'.
Map<String,String> mymap = getSomehow();

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("mytempl.ftl");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

template.process(mymap, sw);
```

And then, the template (`mytempl.ftl`):

```
<h1>${mymap[fizz]}</h1>
```

But when I run this, I get:

```
FreeMarker template error: The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> mymap
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: Is the result of `getSomehow()` definitely non-null?

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner (+1) - **yes**, the map is definitely non-null (confirmed with logging statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to the `process` Method is the "context" of the Template. So to pick specific values from the Map you can just use `<h1>${fizz}</h1>`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Schneider (+1) - what if I need to inject both a `Map<String,String>` and, say, a `FooBar` instance into my template? How do I "combine" the map and the `FooBar` into the same "context" and then, subsequently, access specific keys from inside the map? Thanks again!

Comment: Just use another Map or dedicated Object as the context, e.g. `Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>(); context.put('mymap', mymap); context.put('FooBar', fooBar);`. Then in the template you can access them like `<h1>${mymap[fizz]}</h1>` and `${FooBar.someProperty}`

Comment: In the case where you have `mymap`, it's `mymap.fizz` (or `mymap["fizz"]`) actually.